# PHP Error with syntax : "check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax "

Tags: php, sql, database

Error: INSERT INTO reservations (GameID,Name,Numberofdays,ReservationID,Startdate)VALUES (5,'jp', 4, ,'2016-03-23')
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''2016-03-23')' at line 30 results

The code bellow does insert the information that is inputted from a form even though the SQL query is correct . I have tested and changed the code many times and have discussed and reviewed it with my peers .

Bellow is the code for it :

```
    <div id="content">  
<?php

//variables needed to connect to the database
    $user_name = "root";
    $password = "";
    $database = "game_library";
    $host_name ="localhost";

// Create connection
    $con=mysqli_connect($host_name,$user_name,$password,$database) or die("Error ");
    // Check connection
    if ($con->connect_error) {
        die("Connection failed: " . $con->connect_error);
    } 
 //link the search term to the html page
    $GameID=$_POST['GameID'];
    $Name=$_POST['Name'];
    $Numberofdays=$_POST['Numberofdays'];
    $Startdate=$_POST['Startdate'];

    //sql query to add the data from the form elements to the sql database
    //The reservationID is auto incremented so requires a space 
    $qry_reserve = "INSERT INTO reservations 
    (GameID,Name,Numberofdays,ReservationID,Startdate)VALUES ($GameID,'$Name',
    $Numberofdays, ,'$Startdate')";

    //Runs the query if the database if connection succesful
    if ($con->query($qry_reserve) === TRUE) {
    echo '<br/>';
    echo $Name. ' has been added successfully</h2>';
    echo '<hr>';
    } else {
    echo "Error: " . $qry_reserve . "<br>" . $con->error;
    }

    //show added data & all records to prove they have been added. You don't have to do this
    $qry_show_table = "SELECT * FROM reservations WHERE GameID='$GameID' ";
    $result = mysqli_query($con, $qry_show_table);

    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { // checks if there are more than zero rows returned.
        // output data of each row
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) //puts all the results into an associative array that we can loop through
        {
        echo '<br/>';
        echo 'Name: '.$row['Name'];
        echo '<br/> GameID: '.$row['GameID'];
        echo '<br/> Startdate: '.$row['Startdate'];
        echo '<br/> Numberofdays: '.$row['Numberofdays'];
        echo '<br/>';
        echo '<hr>';
        }
} else {
echo "0 results";
}

$con->close();
?>
```

Comment: Well, *have* you checked the manual for the right syntax for an `INSERT INTO .. VALUES` query...? I'm sure it doesn't specify a `(` before `VALUES`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leave out the parentheses:

```
INSERT INTO reservations 
    VALUES ($GameID, '$Name', $Numberofdays, ??,' $Startdate')
---------------------------------------------^ something needs to go here
```

Or, better yet, list the columns:

```
INSERT INTO reservations(col1, col2, col3, col4, col5)
    VALUES ($GameID, '$Name', $Numberofdays, ??, '$Startdate')
---------------------------------------------^ something needs to go here
```

Note that you have two commas with no value in between.  Perhaps this is a typo, perhaps you intend `NULL` or `DEFAULT` or something else.

Answer (score 0):

You won't need the parenthesis and also you have a extra comma:

```
$qry_reserve = "INSERT INTO reservations VALUES ($GameID,'$Name',$Numberofdays,'$Startdate'";
```

More information at http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp.